# Java: who change size when WeakHashMap's entries evict?

Tags: java, collections

Recently, I try to figure out how `WeakHashMap` works. As code shows, `map.isEmpty()` will return true after `System.gc()` and `size` is strong referenced, so who change size?

```
    WeakHashMap<UniqueKey, BigImage> map = new WeakHashMap<>();

    UniqueKey key = new UniqueKey("abc");
    map.put(key, new BigImage());
    BigImage value = map.get(key);
    assertNotNull(value);

    key = null;
    System.gc();

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    assertTrue(map.isEmpty());
```

Comment: It's the WeakHashMap itself: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/WeakHashMap.java#l363

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the implementation internally:

```
public int size() {
    if (size == 0)
        return 0;
    expungeStaleEntries();
    return size;
}
```

specifically for `expungeStaleEntries` method that uses :

```
/**
 * Reference queue for cleared WeakEntries
 */
private final ReferenceQueue<Object> queue = new ReferenceQueue<>();
```

This method also updates `size`, before it is returned to you.

Answer (score 1):

The stale entries are removed when you call the `size()` method.

The `size()` method internally calls the private method `expungeStaleEntries()` in order to remove the stale entries (of course, if it is not already empty).